# trying to make an afk command for my bot but i am getting this error

Tags: discord.py

```
  async def afk(self, ctx, *args):
    msg = ' '.join(args)
    self.data.append(ctx.author.id)
    self.data.append(msg)
    await ctx.author.edit(nick=f'[AFK] {ctx.author.name}')
    await ctx.send("afk set!")

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message(self, message):
    for i in range(len(self.data)):
      if (f"<@{self.data[i]}>" in message.content) and (not message.author.bot):
        await message.channel.send(f"<@{self.data[i]}> is away right now, they said: {self.data[i+1]}")
        return None
        break

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_typing(self, channel, user, when):
    if user.id in self.data:
      i = self.data.index(user.id)
      self.data.remove(self.data[i+1])
      self.data.remove(user.id)
      nick = ctx.author.name.replace('[AFK]', '')
      await ctx.author.edit(nick=nick)
      await channel.send(f"{user.mention}, Welcome back!")
```

But it is showing *ctx* is not found `nick = ctx.author.name.replace('[AFK]', '')` i have been trying various methods to solve it, but i am not able to fix this, pls help me

Comment: What is not clear? You're trying to access something which isn't in scope.

Comment: Use `user.name.replace('[AFK]', '')` instead of `ctx.author.name.replace('[AFK]', '')`

Answer (score 0):

You're using ctx in a func which doesnt have a ctx arg, you should instead use

```
nick = user.author.name.replace('[AFK]', '')
await user.author.edit(nick=nick)
```